# how to compare in c++ two google::protobuf::Timestamp's

Tags: c++, timestamp, protocol-buffers

what is the most correct way to compare google::protobuf::Timestamp's? the most natural (to me) opeprator for timestamps "<" is not defined for this type.

Should I convert both value to nano for example and compare? Or there is some other handy function? Also I didn't find something like "t.isLarger(t2)" or other method for comparison defined for this type.

Answer (score 1):

The natural thing seems to be to compare the seconds and nanos fields directly:

```cpp
bool operator<(
    const google::protobuf::Timestamp &left,
    const google::protobuf::Timestamp &right )
{
    return left.seconds() == right.seconds() ?
        left.nanos() < right.nanos() :
        left.seconds() < right.seconds();
}
```

You may also want to look at: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.util.time_util

Comment: Thanks. And what do you think about translation of both timestamps to nanoseconds with `int64_t TimeUtil::TimestampToNanoseconds(const Timestamp&)` and comparison of these values? 

like in pseudocode:

`uint64 t1 = TimeUtil::TimestampToNanoseconds(goggle_timestamp1);` 
`uint64 t2 = TimeUtil::TimestampToNanoseconds(google_timestamp2);`

`if (t1 > t2) {...} else {...}`


?

Comment: That would be fine if all your timestamps fit in 63 bits (since `int64_t` is signed).  The Timestamp class is supposed to be valid until the year 9999 (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Timestamp), but you will overflow 63 bits in about 292.3 years ( `~ (2^63) / 1'000'000'000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365.25 )` ).

Answer (score 0):

google::protobuf::util contains overloaded operators <,>,==,!= ....